# Call a function each x second in requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, three.js, requestanimationframe

I'm working on some personal project by Three.js. I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` function. I want to call a function each 2 seconds. I've search but I couldn't find anything useful.
My code is like this:

```
function render() {
   // each 2 seconds call the createNewObject() function
   if(eachTwoSecond) {
      createNewObject();
   }
   requestAnimationFrame(render);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) passes single parameter to your callback which indicates the current time (in ms) when `requestAnimationFrame` fires the callback. You can use it to calculate time interval between `render()` calls.

```
var last = 0; // timestamp of the last render() call
function render(now) {
    // each 2 seconds call the createNewObject() function
    if(!last || now - last >= 2*1000) {
        last = now;
        createNewObject();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and came up with this solution:

```
let t = 0
const interval = 2 * 60 // there are 60 ticks per second

function render() {
  if (++t % interval == 0)
    doSomething()

  requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
```

UPDATE: This solution is framerate dependent, so it is not good.

Comment: If you have a 144hz frame rate, it will last 1 second. And on a 30hz screen (like an unplugged laptop), it will last 0.5 second. You can't rely on framerate as a time unit.

Answer (score 2):

this function will print a number every 2 seconds

```
let last = 0;
let num = 0;
let speed = 2;

function main(timeStamp) {
  let timeInSecond = timeStamp / 1000;

  if (timeInSecond - last >= speed) {
    last = timeInSecond;
    console.log(++num);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `requestAnimationFrame` will give you an available frame in 60fps (if your browser can keep up with it) it seems perfectly fine to wait 2 seconds and request a frame. This way the browser will give you a frame exactly after these 2 seconds, which in most cases will be in an instant:

```
        function render() {
            // each 2 seconds call the createNewObject() function
            createNewObject();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        setInterval(function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to decrease fps. I want fps to remain 60. there are other animations exist in the project which I need them to be smooth while animating. decreasing fps is not a solution I guess.

Comment: `setInterval` has tons of issues when used in this way which cause huge performance problems on top of ruining your animation. Instead you should use `requestAnimationFrame`.

More info: https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2021-12/request-animation-frame/

Answer (score 0):

### Simple JS Timer that runs every given seconds

Modification of the MDN Example --> [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#notes).

```js
/*
<div id="test">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
*/
const element = document.getElementById('test');
let start, previousTimeStamp;


timerConfig = {
    frequency: 1, // Seconds
    stopAt: 10, // Seconds,
    pos: 1,  // px
    posStep: 10,  // px
    updatePos: () => {
        timerConfig.pos = timerConfig.pos + timerConfig.posStep;
    }
}

function timer(timestamp) {    
    if (start === undefined)  start = timestamp;
    if (previousTimeStamp === undefined)  previousTimeStamp = timestamp;
    const seconds = timerConfig.frequency*1000;
    const tick = timestamp - previousTimeStamp; 

    function trigger() {
        element.style.transform = 'translateX(' + timerConfig.pos + 'px)';
    }

    if (tick >= seconds) {
        trigger();
        previousTimeStamp = timestamp; // Updating The Timer each second
        timerConfig.updatePos();
    }
    if (timestamp < timerConfig.stopAt*1000) requestAnimationFrame(timer); // 10 Seconds    
    
}

requestAnimationFrame(timer);
```