# Call a function each 100 milliseconds using requestAnimationFrame on chrome

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I want to execute a function every 100 milliseconds. it can be done using an interval like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
console.log('done')

}, 100);
```

But this takes 2.5 to 3 percent CPU usage on chrome.

Now I want to do the same thing using `requestAnimationFrame` to test the CPU usage and compare the performances.

How can I Call a function or console log every 100 milliseconds using requestAnimationFrame on chrome?

Here is same stack question but I can't make a working code: [Call a function each x second in requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743592/call-a-function-each-x-second-in-requestanimationframe)

Comment: What makes you think it would be any better with rAF?

Comment: *but I can't make a working code*..ok so where is this code? Basically this seems like a duplicate of the question you've linked. If that hasn't worked then you need to be clear about why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost you're seeing isn't primarily `setInterval`'s internals, it's the work to call your callback and the work your callback is doing. That's not going to change for the better with `requestAnimationFrame`. **Much** more likely it'll get worse.

Here's how you'd do it¹, but I suspect you'll find you're better off doing what you're doing or not doing either of them:

```
var last = Date.now();
requestAnimationFrame(function tick() {
    if (Date.now() - last >= 92) { // Why 92 instead of 100? See ¹ below.
        doYourWorkHere();

        last = Date.now();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});
```

Note that your function is now doing at least slightly more work, and being called **much** more often (every ~17ms instead of every ~100ms).

**So**: You're probably better off sticking with `setInterval`. If the CPU load of the work being done every 100ms is too high, you'll need to back off the interval.

---

¹ Why 92 instead of 100? Because each callback is about ~17ms after the last, so if you don't do your processing when it's been [say] 95ms since the last call, you won't get a chance until ~17ms later when it's been ~112ms since the last call. 92 is 100 - (17 / 2) rounded down, so at 91 you'll wait until 108, but at 92 you'll go right away. This helps you stay near every 100ms. Live example:

```js
var counter = 0;
var last = Date.now();
requestAnimationFrame(function tick() {
    let diff;
    if ((diff = Date.now() - last) >= 92) {
        console.log(`Time since last: ${diff}ms`);

        last = Date.now();
        ++counter;
    }
    if (counter < 20) { // Just to keep the example from running forever
      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```